# MSChart: Label format

Tags: .net, mschart

How can I format chart label?
I need to see only 2 digits after point.

I try `chart.ChartAreas.First().AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "#.##";` and `0.00`

Also I try to set `Series[0].LabelFormat = "0.00"` and `#.##`

and without success.

What is wrong?

[image: current chart]

Answer (score 7):

Try setting `.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format` to `"{0:0.00}"` - I had to do it recently on one of my charts so it should work.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
chart.ChartAreas.First().AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "F2";
```

and the details on this page
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could also iterate over your list. Here is what I did for percentages:

```
foreach (var point in Chart.Series[0].Points)
{
    point.Label = point.YValues[0].ToString("P2");
    point.LegendText = point.YValues[0].ToString("P2") + " - " + point.AxisLabel;
}
```

Set

Answer (score 0):

Set the YValueType="Double" and the LabelFormat="C" within the  tag.